# C# WPF ICollectionView Filter not firing on custom UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have developed an editable combobox with a checkbox drop down list. The user can type in the textbox section of the combobox and it should filter the items. But I'm having an issue with the filter not firing when the FilterText is changed.

This is my Usercontrol XAML. All code is simplified.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbBox"  IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="False" 
ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredItems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
Text="{Binding FilterText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
IsDropDownOpen="{Binding DropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" >
```

Code behind looks like this:

```
public ICollectionView FilteredItems
{
    get { return (ICollectionView)GetValue(FilteredItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FilteredItemsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FilteredItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FilteredItems", typeof(ICollectionView), typeof(ComboCheckBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public string FilterText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(FilterTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FilterTextProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FilterText", typeof(string), typeof(ComboCheckBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public ObservableCollection<Item> mItems
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<Item>)GetValue(mItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(mItemsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty mItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("mItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<Item>), typeof(ComboCheckBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public ComboCheckBox()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    FilteredItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(mItems);
    // apply filtering delegate
    FilteredItems.Filter = i =>
    {
        // This will be invoked for every item in the underlying collection every time Refresh is invoked
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterText)) return true;
        Item m = (Item)i;
        return m.Name.ToLower().Contains(FilterText.ToLower());
    };
}
```

So in my constructor I apply the filter delegate. And below is my MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowsVM />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <dd:ComboCheckBox x:Name="combo" Width="400" Height="30" FilteredItems="{Binding DataSource}" mItems="{Binding OC}" />
</Grid>
```

And the ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> _oc;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> OC
    {
        get { return _oc; }
        set
        {
            _oc = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OC");
        }
    }

private ICollectionView _datasouorce;
    public ICollectionView DataSource
    {
        get { return _datasouorce; }
        set
        {
            _datasouorce = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DataSource");
        }
    }

    public MainWindowsVM()
    {
        oc = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        oc.Add(new Item { Name = "ACT", IsChecked = false });
        oc Add(new Item { Name = "ADVICENNE", IsChecked = false });
        oc.Add(new Item { Name = "NOVARTIS", IsChecked = false });

        DataSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(oc);
    }
```

With the above code I'm able to successfully view the items in my drop down list which tells me that the DataSource was bound to FilteredItems correctly on my MainWindow, but for some reason when typing in the textbox no filter occurs. If however I place the filter delegate in the Main Window VM then it works, but I want this logic in the Usercontrol codebehind, not in the MainWindow.

Any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: I added this to FilteredItems="{Binding DataSource}" and now I'm not getting any items in my combobox. Before I was, but the filter was not working.

Comment: Are you getting any bindng errors in output?

Comment: It compiles and runs fine, but I noticed in my Mainwindow xaml mItems={Binding OC} is underlined with message that Object reference not set to an instance of an object. But the program still compiles.

Comment: What do you mean by filter delegate? How do you place it in MainWindow? And what is DataSource2? Also, by 'Are you getting any bindnig errors' i mean runtimes error, these which appears in ouput when you run program

Comment: Sorry I edited my above comment, it should be OC not DataSource2. By filtering delegate I just mean the filter block of code which I defined in the Usercontrol code-behind main constructor. If I put that same code in the MainWindow VM constructor, and expose the FilterText property from the Usercontrol to the MainWindow, it will work. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I don't get any runtime errors in the output.